# Why is my useeffect clean up function not executing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why is my useeffect clean up function not executing?

"Downloaded" prints in the console, but "Cleaned up" never prints.

I need it to be called after the useeffect runs (every time) to clear up memory.

Here's my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!downloadedFile) return;
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = downloadedFile.file;
    link.setAttribute("download", downloadedFile.filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    console.log("downloaded");
    return () => {
      console.log("cleaned up");
      link.remove();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadedFile.file);
      dispatch(cleanUpAfterDownload());
    };
  }, [downloadedFile]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The clean up function will run when `downloadedFile` changes. Are you sure it's changing?

Comment: I assume it's supposed to run right after downloaded is logged. Am I mistaken?

Comment: To answer you, yes downloadedFile changes which is why the downloaded log prints. I'm stumped as to why 'cleaned up' isn't logged soon after.

Comment: I still don't  know why the cleanup function isn't being called, but I changed my code to this:   useEffect(() => {
    if (!downloadedFile) return;
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = downloadedFile.file;
    link.setAttribute("download", downloadedFile.filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    console.log("downloaded");
    link.remove();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadedFile.file);
    dispatch(cleanUpAfterDownload());
  }, [downloadedFile]);